# Verb + shi vs verb + tari --> what's the difference?

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs

After a verb, they both used to imply "...and other things" or "among other things". What's the difference between them? When is used one and not the other? Which is more common? Are they really more or less the same?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41969/difference-between-し-and-たり